# cmake ignores static library link request

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I've searched hours on how to solve this and everything I tried did not work.
I'm trying to link statically with certain libraries, (libPoco, libmysqlcpp, libmysqlclient, libssl).

I'm using cmake, and although I am defining the static library, cmake simply looks up the dynamic one. I know I have all the required libraries in static archive in my filesystem, and I know where they are.

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH}
              /lib
              /usr/lib
              /usr/lib64
              /usr/local/lib
              /usr/local/lib64
              /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)

find_library(POCO_NET NAMES libPocoNet.a PATHS CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH STATIC IMPORTED)
find_library(POCO_UTIL NAMES libPocoUtil.a PATHS CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH STATIC IMPORTED)
find_library(POCO_XML NAMES libPocoXML.a PATHS CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH STATIC IMPORTED)
find_library (MYSQL_CLIENT NAMES libmysqlclient.a PATHS CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH STATIC IMPORTED)
find_library (MYSQL_CPP NAMES libmysqlpp.a PATHS CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH STATIC IMPORTED)
find_library (LIBSSL NAMES libssl.a PATHS CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH STATIC IMPORTED)

if (POCO_NET AND POCO_UTIL AND POCO_XML AND MYSQL_CLIENT AND MYSQL_CPP AND LIBSSL)
  message(STATUS ${POCO_NET})
  message(STATUS ${POCO_UTIL})
  message(STATUS ${POCO_XML})
  message(STATUS ${MYSQL_CLIENT})
  message(STATUS ${MYSQL_CPP})
  message(STATUS ${LIBSSL})
  target_link_libraries(icarus 
            PocoNet
            PocoUtil
            PocoXML
            mysqlpp
            mysqlclient
            ssl)
else ()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "FATAL ERROR: missing library")
endif (POCO_NET AND POCO_UTIL AND POCO_XML AND MYSQL_CLIENT AND MYSQL_CPP AND LIBSSL)
```

But when I run **cmake ..** all I get is:

```
-- /usr/local/lib/libPocoNet.so
-- /usr/local/lib/libPocoUtil.so
-- /usr/local/lib/libPocoXML.so
-- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
-- /usr/lib/libmysqlpp.so
-- /usr/lib/libssl.so
```

And when I try to compile, I get undefined references since I am using a -static flag.
What am I missing here?
Is there a way to force cmake to lookup the static libraries instead of the dynamic ones?
Am I going the wrong way about this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a wee bit confused between the [`add_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_library) and [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_library) commands.  `find_library` doesn't take arguments of `STATIC` or `IMPORTED`.

Also, you've not wrapped `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` in `${}` inside your `find_library` call, so you're effectively passing 3 paths of "CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH", "STATIC" and "IMPORTED" to CMake's search routine, not the intended 6 paths of `${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH}`.

Finally, since `${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH}` is already the first port of call in CMake search routine, there's no need to add it explicitly to the `find_library` commands.

So you can do something like:

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH}
              /lib
              /usr/lib
              /usr/lib64
              /usr/local/lib
              /usr/local/lib64
              /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)

find_library(POCO_NET NAMES libPocoNet.a)
find_library(POCO_UTIL NAMES libPocoUtil.a)
find_library(POCO_XML NAMES libPocoXML.a)
find_library(MYSQL_CLIENT NAMES libmysqlclient.a)
find_library(MYSQL_CPP NAMES libmysqlpp.a)
find_library(LIBSSL NAMES libssl.a PATHS)

if(POCO_NET AND POCO_UTIL AND POCO_XML AND MYSQL_CLIENT AND MYSQL_CPP AND LIBSSL)
  message(STATUS ${POCO_NET})
  message(STATUS ${POCO_UTIL})
  message(STATUS ${POCO_XML})
  message(STATUS ${MYSQL_CLIENT})
  message(STATUS ${MYSQL_CPP})
  message(STATUS ${LIBSSL})
  target_link_libraries(icarus 
            ${POCO_NET}
            ${POCO_UTIL}
            ${POCO_XML}
            ${MYSQL_CLIENT}
            ${MYSQL_CPP}
            ${LIBSSL})
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "FATAL ERROR: missing library")
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did what you said, but I am still getting the same output from cmake (shows the *.so) and a link error of attempted static link to dynamic object. It still seems to be ignoring the *.a

Comment: Nevermind, you were right, cmake was cached, deleted the debug directory and tried again and it uses the *.a now. Thank you ! :)

Comment: Also, FIY: set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})

Comment: @Alex Yes, I should have mentioned about deleting your CMakeCache.txt - sorry!  Good point also about `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES`.